# Fluid object going through obstale, changing size and shape

Tags: fluid-simulation

I was trying to simulate an melting ice cube by letting a fluid object (cube) slowly spread in its container. Doing this i ran into some weird glitches.

The glitch that bothers me the most is that the fluid stretches along the x axis until it hits the domains edge. It even goes through obstacles.
[image]
In this case the fluid domain is close to the size of the pot my ice cube is melting in. If i stretch the domain any further the liquid also extends (only on the x axis tho) until it hits the border of the domain.

This is what i tried so far to solve the problem (nothing really helped):

- Change the fluids volume initialization to shell: This fixed the deformation and stretching of the fluid but made the animation look very unrealistic. Looked more like the ice cube is collapsing instead of melting
- Change the size and shape of the fluid object: This did not show any effect
- Increase the fluids resolution: This did not show any effect

Here is my fluid object
[image]

Here is my .blend file
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the normals.  You need to select your ice cube, go into edit mode, select all vertices, and choose Mesh-->Normals-->Recalculate Outside.  The sim then sims as it should.

Comment: Big thanks, you just spared me a lot of grey hair :)

Answer (score 2):

The container looks like it's doubled-walled, and is probably too thin for the fluid collision detection to work with. I would suggest making a thicker pot just for the simulation and swap in the current model for rendering.

You can make the pot thicker by adding a displacement modifier on top of the fluid sim modifier, which will push out the geometry along the normals.

[image]

Comment: Do you also have an explanation for the stretching part? I already thought of the walls being to thin, but that wouldn't explain why the actual fluid is later on way bigger than the initial fluid object. As i mentioned the fluid will stretch into infinity if i expand my fluid domain. This shouldn't depend on the obstacle or can it?